# Wordpress: After transfer images to cdn featured images and thumbnails gone

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-s3

so this is very confusing to me,

i recently transferred all media to amazon S3 and files to amazon EC2, I'm holding my MySql in amazon RDS service. Before transfer i have changed with notepad all media path from:

> http://www.olddomain.com/wp-content/uploads/

To

> http://www.AmaazonS3ServiceUrl.com/wp-content/uploads/

And i have uploaded it, so first day was everything ok, i saw images from amazons3, i media section of wordpress admin menu was amazons3 media url, but after a day when i was configurating the wordpress, something just happened, and everything was reverted all thumbnails featured images just gone, now it shows on thumbnails url my

> http://www.olddomain.com/wp-content/uploads

/

But if i go to ppost it shows insite it amazon s3 photo displaying.

I have tried:

1. Restore Database several times (4 or 5)
2. Tried regenerate thumbnails plugins (3 different, waited several hours because i have more than 24k photos, didn't help)
3. Tried clean cache
4. Tried updating database sql query with: `UPDATE wp_posts SET  guid = REPLACE (guid, 'http://oldcomain.com/', 'http://mynewcdndomain.com/') WHERE post_type = 'attachment';` or UPDATE `wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 'olddocmain.com', 'newcdndomain.com') WHERE post_type = 'attachment';`

Inside Wordpress admin in media section there is no photo.s displaying properly, before when i just transferred it was displaying properly and showing that they are in amazon, now it says that it was not able to find any photos ant path is of my domain not amazon S3.

Does anyone know why this happens and what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i think this will come very handy to people like me.

If any person wants to transfer all his existing images to CDN doesn't matter amazon or other that person should use w3 total cache because that plugin allows u rename all existing media urls and much more i have fixed my problem with that plugin i hope people who will find this topic and will have same issue will fix this annoying problem also.